# How do I set up Junit in Pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, junit, pydev

I'm new to Python and PyDev, but not to Junit. I'm probably being dense, but I don't know how to get Junit working with Python in PyDev (in Eclipse). I Googled around for a while, but don't see anything obvious. In Eclipse I see a way to create a Junit test case and test suite ***for Java*** by right clicking on my Python package. How do I create the same for Python?

Comment: JUnit is for Java. You probably want the Python [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) module.

Comment: I just found a menu item: run as -> Python unit test. It looks like it uses something called PyUnit. It ran *something*. Now at least I have a term to search for how to create tests.